# How do I programmatically scroll a control in Windows?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I have some controls like TWebBrowser, TRichText etc. which I want to scroll them (horizontally and/or vertically) from my program.

How do I achieve this?

PS: I think that it is doable by sending some messages to their handles but I don't know now which ones.

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WM_VSCROLL` and/or `WM_HSCROLL`.  GetScrollInfo() to find out how far you can go.

Answer (score 1):

For edit controls, look at the `EM_SCROLL` and `EM_LINESCROLL` messages.